# How do you print an environment variable in Perl/Plack

Tags: perl, environment-variables, plack

I'm trying to switch out 'Ben' with an environment variable using Perl/Plack. If the environment variable is set (e.g. 'Dave'), then it will print out "Powered by Dave". But it if is not set, it will default to 'Ben'.

Currently, the following program works when using `plackup -r`

```
#!/usr/bin/env plackup

my $app = sub {
        my $env = shift;

        return [
            200,
            ['Content-Type', 'text/plain'],
            ['Powered by Ben'],
        ];

};
```

Currently, my cpanfile contains the following

```
requires 'Plack' => '1.0028';
requires 'CGI::Emulate::PSGI' => '0.15';
requires 'CGI::Compile' => '0.16';
```

Comment: My perl is a bit rusty, so please check this:  For the Perl statement `if ($foo) {x} else {y}`, how does this behave if $foo does not exist?  My guess is that an extant `$foo` will execute the first block and a nonexistent `$foo` will execute the second block.

Comment: something like `[ sprintf('Powered by %s', $ENV{xxx} || 'Ben') ]` as single quoted strings are not interpolated

Answer (score 1):

By `Environment Varaible` do you mean, the operating system's environment or the plack request enviroment and thus an HTTP request parameter?  (they're completely different).

If the former, you can access it via the `%ENV` hash.

If the latter, you should read the documentation for [Plack::Request](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Plack-0.9952/lib/Plack/Request.pm).

*(note: I've never used plack; I'm only going by the docs)*

Comment: if the latter, it should be just in the `$env` - already in the code :)